# How to choose multiple keywords

Tags: php, html, wordpress, search, keyword

I am using a wordpress template, it is called Houzez, which only has three search options for the written search form, the three options are these:

1. Property title and content.
2. Property address, street, zip code and ID.
3. Area, City and State.

   But I want to use the three search options at the same time, although there is no such option, so I looked in the editor of the theme and found the codes but I am not a specialist in the subject, I am just an entrepreneur, so I ask for your help so that you can help me find a way to do it through the codes.

Thanks.
Sorry if there are errors in my writing, I'm not very good at English.

#### Houzez: keyword-banner.php (template-parts/search/fields/keyword-banner.php)

```
<?php 
$keyword_field = houzez_option('keyword_field');
if( $keyword_field == 'prop_title' ) {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_keyword', 'Enter Keyword...');

} else if( $keyword_field == 'prop_city_state_county' ) {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_csa', 'Search City, State or Area');

} else if( $keyword_field == 'prop_address' ) {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_address', 'Enter an address, town, street, zip or property ID');

} else {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_keyword', 'Enter Keyword...');
}

$keyword = isset ( $_GET['keyword'] ) ? $_GET['keyword'] : ''; ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="search-icon">
        <input name="keyword" type="text" data-type="banner" class="houzez-keyword-autocomplete form-control" value="<?php echo esc_attr($keyword); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr($keyword_placeholder); ?>">
    </div><!-- search-icon -->
</div><!-- form-group -->
```

#### Houzez: keyword.php (template-parts/search/fields/keyword.php)

```
<?php 
$keyword_field = houzez_option('keyword_field');
if( $keyword_field == 'prop_title' ) {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_keyword', 'Enter Keyword...');

} else if( $keyword_field == 'prop_city_state_county' ) {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_csa', 'Search City, State or Area');

} else if( $keyword_field == 'prop_address' ) {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_address', 'Enter an address, town, street, zip or property ID');

} else {
    $keyword_placeholder = houzez_option('srh_keyword', 'Enter Keyword...');
}

$keyword_autocomplete = houzez_option('keyword_autocomplete');

$keyword = isset ( $_GET['keyword'] ) ? $_GET['keyword'] : ''; ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="search-icon">
        <?php if( $keyword_autocomplete != 1 ) { ?>
        <input name="keyword" type="text" class="<?php houzez_ajax_search(); ?> houzez-keyword-autocomplete form-control" value="<?php echo esc_attr($keyword); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr($keyword_placeholder); ?>">
        <div id="auto_complete_ajax" class="auto-complete"></div>
        <?php } else { ?>

            <input name="keyword" type="text" class="houzez-keyword-autocomplete form-control" value="<?php echo esc_attr($keyword); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr($keyword_placeholder); ?>">
            <div id="auto_complete_ajax" class="auto-complete"></div>

        <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- search-icon -->
</div><!-- form-group -->
```

IMAGE:

[Screenshot of the options that can be chosen, as you can see there is not an option to choose all the options](https://pe.urbanexo.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Sin-titulo.png)